# How to Actually Use FFT to implement Low Pass Filter

Tags: matlab, filter, fft, convolution, lowpass-filter

I have removed most of the original question but have reworded the lower part to be more specific:

Top of Original Q:
I have searched high and low for a practical guide to implement a simple 50Hz low pass filter on a signal.I understand the theory but its the practical but that's missing. If I was using MATLAB it would be trivial because there are so many examples but I am coding this by code.

Edited Q:
Firstly thanks to the people who answered, it is appreciated.

Secondly as to MATLAB yes there are many examples (some quite cryptic examples!) out there but this is a hard coded application and using MATLAB is not possible so I want to do this by hand. It is also a learning exercise for me and I just need to get started.

Perhaps if I restate the question in an alternative stepwise fashion:
I have my data and want to use a filter lets say a Gaussian LP filter at 50Hz.

Do I do this as follows:

0: FFT Signal data S(t) -> S(f) with full complex FFT

1: Obtain Gaussian frequency resp for 50Hz LP as e.g. F(f) = exp(c(f-50)^2)

2: iFFT Gaussian filter F(f) -> F(t)

3: shift and window F(t)

4: Inverse filter back to f domain: iFFT F(t) -> F(f)

5: Multiply signal by filter: F(f) * S(f) ->R(f)

6: Inverse result to get filtered signal S(t): iFFT R(f) -> R(t)

7: Repeat until filter parameters OK

Seems more complicated and not what I remember from many years ago doing maths at uni.

Comment: It depends how advanced or basic that which you want to have in the end shall work. In theory, the FFT of a finite series (typically 2^N long) is the spectrum of your time series with a rectangular wave form (you cut hard into the time series where you start and you cut hard into the series where you stop). If you now multiply your transformed complex series with a rectangle cutting off at 50HZ, you get the same aliasing and ripple and whatnot effects as you get with window-less fft as well. Matlab often silently applies a window function (hanning, bartlet, ...) to its fourier functions.

Comment: For practical applications you would use a (linear phase) FIR  or IIR filter for your efficient lowpass filtering. How to compute the filter coefficients for that? See your favorite signal processing book. There are many approaches to get good filter coefficients. Matlab also has a filter design feature in signal processing toolbox (at least it had 15 years ago).

Comment: Simple answer: Don't. Filter design is a complex problem, and if you attempt to do this without thorough knowledge you will most likely do something wrong. Better use the filter design and application facilities of Matlab's *Signal Processing Toolbox*.

Comment: For a simple FIR filter including the option to low-pass, see [`fir1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir1.html)

Comment: I have posted a longer answer over in dsp.stackexchange.com [link](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25705/practical-guide-to-filtering-with-fft) here